# Angular2 change detection infinite loop in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firefox

I have randomly found that there are some triggers that can cause an infinite change detection loop in Firefox in an Angular2 app.

I have replicated one on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VTS89eJkePLrJjuoDzOK

The ScrollToFixed plugin does some basic dom manipulation and applies some styles. However if you scroll the "Main" section and then the "Sidebar" section, you will see that doCheck is called infinitely.

I have also been able to trigger an infinite loop in Firefox by triggering a marker within a Google map to start animating.

The infinite loop does not occur in IE, Safari or Chrome. I am unsure if this is a problem with Angular2 or Firefox, but I cannot find the source of the issue.

**app.ts**

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, DoCheck} from 'angular2/angular2';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class App implements DoCheck{
  constructor()
    {

        $('#sidebar').scrollToFixed();
    }

    doCheck(){
      console.log('do check')
    }

}

bootstrap(App);
```

**template.html**

```
<div id="main">Main
</div>

<div id="sidebar">Sidebar
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
Sidebar bottom
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#main {
  float: left;
  width: 66.66667%;
  height:10000px;
}

#sidebar {
  overflow:scroll;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
  background-color: #f9f8f9;
  height:200px;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>angular2 playground</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.44/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/master/jquery-scrolltofixed.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this only happens in Firefox and why it generates an infinite loop, but the error thrown indicates that you try to apply `$('#sidebar').scrollToFixed();` before the sidebar is created. By default in Angular in the constructor no DOM elements have been rendered yet. The sidebar will only be available after initializing the DOM by Angular. You can put your code in ngAfterViewInit and it will work.

You can read https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks for more information

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using **check** in lifecycle, one should be careful and confirm whether not to run for infinite (might hangup your app); I faced similar issue (Life cycle hook) `ngAfterContentInit()` has resolved.